# Match freebase MID to real expression

Tags: semantic-web, freebase, knowledge-graph

I'm trying to match the MIDs corresponding to the freebase database to its real meaning. For example, /m/02hcv8 stands for Eastern Time Zone.
Unfortunately all I get are dead links.
I'm aware that freebase is dead. But I would like to know if anyone has any ideas on how to match MIDs to specific terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### From Wikidata

Wikidata [has Freebase mappings](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:WikiProject_Freebase), which you can query with SPARQL on https://query.wikidata.org/:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?concept ?conceptLabel
WHERE {
  
  BIND( "/m/02hcv8" AS ?freebaseId ) .
  
  ?concept wdt:P646 ?freebaseId . 
  
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

}
```

(I don’t know the current coverage.)

### From the Freebase dump

Google offers the Freebase dump for download under https://developers.google.com/freebase. You could import it into your knowledge graph, and use SPARQL to find the relevant data:

```
# all triples about /m/02hcv8
<http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/m.02hcv8> ?p ?o .
```

Comment: I would recommend removing the `LIMIT 1` from the SPARQL just in case there are duplicate mappings. It shouldn't happen, but if it does, you'll want to know. Here's a direct link to the query in WQDS - https://w.wiki/7Vxn

Comment: @TomMorris: Right, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any idea where the identifiers ( wdf and others), their meaning and use are listed?

Comment: @Kyv I'm not sure I understand your question, but `wdt:` is a prefix used for wikidata properties and the properties themselves each have their own page e.g. https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P646 and which you can browse (https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special:ListProperties/external-id) or search.

Comment: re: coverage - Wikidata currently has ~4.5M Freebase identifiers total for all entities while Freebase had ~57M entities, but coverage will vary greatly by entity type. Freebase had 4.5M people, while Wikidata has 2.6M authors with VIAF IDs and 1.4M authors with Freebase IDs, but I'd have to do more analysis to see how many of the Freebase authors are represented in Wikidata https://web.archive.org/web/20151130054957/http://www.freebase.com/people

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few more ways that you can resolve Freebase MIDs:

1. https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/m/02hcv8 (All Freebase MIDs are Google Knowledge Graph IDs too, but the inverse isn't true)
2. https://angryloki.github.io/mreid-resolver/#/m/02hcv8 (can be used to resolve a bunch of other identifier types too)
3. https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/http://www.freebase.com/m/02hcv8 (added bonus - you get to see what the actual Freebase page looked like back in the day)
4. https://freebase.toolforge.org/m/02hcv8 (seems to have some reliability/performance issues)